# operator!() and operator--() in if condition

Tags: c++

Why does the output of this code not show `count==4`? `operator--` has greater precedence over `operator!`, right?

```
int main()
{
   int found = 0, count = 5;
   if (!found || --count == 0)
       cout << "danger" << endl;
   cout << "count=" << count<< endl;
}
```

Comment: [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: There are other operators in the expression.   The relative precedence of `!` and `--` doesn't matter, since `||` does short-circuit evaluation (i.e. `!found` will be evaluated first, and `--count == 0` will only be evaluated if `!found` is non-zero, which it isn't).

Comment: I know about short circuit but isn't the prefix decrement the top priority first? i mean shouldn't it first decrease count to 4 and then check the condition?

Comment: That's not really how operator precedence works. Unrelated operations in different subexpressions can normally be evaluated in any order. Precedence is used only to resolve ambiguity, where one primary expression could possibly be the operand to multiple possible operators.

Comment: The first expression (`!found`) has greater precedence over the second expression (`--counter`).

Comment: @barakmanos you are confusing precedence with order of evaluation.

Comment: @yurikilochek: I was just using OP's "language" (taken directly from the opening statement in the question).

Comment: Yes in this case the logical operators guarantee that their left operand is evaluated first. In most other cases the compiler could evaluate the expressions in either order, which is why things like `i = i++ + ++i` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Precedence of `--` and `!` does not matter here, as they are both prefix and are applied to different subexpressions anyway. What you are observing is a short-circuiting of `||`: since left operand it `true`, result of OR is true regardless of the value of right operand, so there is no need to waste time evaluating it, so it doesn't.